Jquery Nice Select: Keep Background Color When Hover to Another Option
I'm using Nice Select, https://github.com/hernansartorio/jquery-nice-select.
How do I keep the background color of the selected option when I hover to another option? Because when I hover to another option, the background of the selected option disappears.

Here's my code:


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('select').niceSelect();
});
.nice-select .option:hover,
.nice-select .option.selected {
    color: #000 !important;
    background-color: #999 !important;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-nice-select/1.1.0/js/jquery.nice-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-nice-select/1.1.0/css/nice-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<select class="drizy-custom-select" id="text-preview">
  <option value="text-preview-1" selected="">The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog</option>
  <option value="text-preview-2">Quizzical twins proved my hijack-bug fix</option>
  <option value="text-preview-3">Cozy sphinx waves quart jug of bad milk</option>
  <option value="text-preview-4">Fix problem quickly with galvanized jets</option>
  <option value="text-preview-5">Aa Bb Cc Dd Ee Ff Gg Hh Ii Jj Kk Ll Mm Nn Oo Pp...</option>
</select>



But it doesn't work.

Have you tried adding !important, like so: .nice-select .option:hover, .nice-select .option.selected {   color: #000 !important;   background-color: #898987 !important; }?

I've tried it, but it doesn't work.

It doesn't work, on selected option, the background color disappears when I hover to another option. The background should stay until I choose another option. I used Chrome and Safari, same result.

Yes, As I see the background gets transparent by this rule: .nice-select .list:hover .option:not(:hover) {background-color: transparent !important;} it should be somehow overridden by a new same declaration in the CSS...

Aah yes, it's working now, I change .nice-select .list:hover .option:not(:hover) { background-color: none !important; }. Thank you for your help.

The .nice-select .list:hover .option:not(:hover) {background-color: transparent !important;} rule makes the problem. Try adding the overriding rule to the end of the document, like so:


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('select').niceSelect();
});
.nice-select .option:hover,
.nice-select .option.selected {
    color: #000 !important;
    background-color: #999 !important;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-nice-select/1.1.0/js/jquery.nice-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-nice-select/1.1.0/css/nice-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<select class="drizy-custom-select" id="text-preview">
  <option value="text-preview-1" selected="">The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog</option>
  <option value="text-preview-2">Quizzical twins proved my hijack-bug fix</option>
  <option value="text-preview-3">Cozy sphinx waves quart jug of bad milk</option>
  <option value="text-preview-4">Fix problem quickly with galvanized jets</option>
  <option value="text-preview-5">Aa Bb Cc Dd Ee Ff Gg Hh Ii Jj Kk Ll Mm Nn Oo Pp...</option>
</select>

<style>
.nice-select .list:hover .option:not(:hover) {
    background-color: red !important;
}
</style>




It's working now, I change .nice-select .list:hover .option:not(:hover) { background-color: none !important; }. Thank you for your help.

You're welcome, my friend!
